# Get version of External Assembly in Dot Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a few nuget packages (EF Core for instance) and I want to be able to get the package version for logging. Is there an easy way (Reflection maybe) to get the version number?

Answer (score 0):

For cases, when a version of the Nuget package is the same as for the shipped assembly, you may try the following:

```
  // using System.Reflection; 

  var version = typeof(<any type from an assembly which version you need>)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .Assembly
        .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
        .InformationalVersion;
```

For example, to get the version of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package`:

```
  var version = typeof(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFactory)
        .GetTypeInfo()
        .Assembly
        .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()
        .InformationalVersion;
```

Comment: Is there a way to enumerate over installed assemblies? I know that could be dangerous from a perf standpoint but I am curious.

Comment: @IsaacLevin look into [Equivalent for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/919) open issue in coreclr