# In the C# project .csproj file, how to dynamically obtain the referenced package name and version?

Tags: c#, csproj

example

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);USE_MYSQL_CONNECTOR;</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I want to be able to add `AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions` to `DefineConstants`.

I expect to be able to call different APIs based on different package versions, like

```cs
#if AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions
AgileObjects.Warp(arg1,arg2)
#else
AgileObjects.Warp(arg1)
#endif
```

Because different package versions provide different APIs, I hope to be able to perceive the version used in the project and decide to use a specific API.

I tried some open source libraries like ThisAssembly, but no luck

##refs
https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/949

Comment: Such "if" construct is called a [preprocessor directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives).

Comment: Anyhow: why add the check that way? The Project shouldn't compile if you reference things in a namespace that doesn't exist. Sure, you could use reflection, but since the project shouldn't compile, the reflection is never executed.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, I know. I want to be able to expose the name and version of PackageReference to C# code, just add it to DefineConstants, which allows me to use them in C#.

Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: I expect to be able to call different APIs based on different package versions, like
```csharp
#if AgileObjects.ReadableExpressions
AgileObjects.Warp(arg1,arg2)
#else
AgileObjects.Warp(arg1)
#endif
```

Comment: Just read the assembly using reflection in that case. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45248332/get-version-of-external-assembly-in-dot-net-core-2).

Comment: Hi, using reflection is an escape path, but I don't want to use it.

Comment: Try to do that another way. Define the constant based on the version of the package. This question may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694283/defineconstants-in-csproj-file-if-i-have-a-reference-to-some-dll

Comment: @Artur defining things in two places is an anti pattern, as they tend to go out of sync. For example: if anybody ever updates the package through the package manager, the constant will not be updated. Reflection is the proper way. Reflection has a bad rep. because people have used it incorrectly in the past. But Reflection is not that bad and actually the best way to go in a lot of situations. Sure, a Reflection call requires some resources, but usually you only need to do it once and then cache the result for instance

Comment: I think we should not be troubled by patterns, just choose the right way at the right time.
We often use conditional compilation to perform some things, maybe reflection can also be done but it is not necessarily a reasonable choice. For example, I don't want some code to enter the final product.

Comment: @JHBonarius, I'm not sure what "two places" you mean. I suggest adding a constraint to the constant definition, which is based on the package version.

Comment: @Artur the linked answer doesn't show that. Maybe you could add an answer which demonstrates how you can define a constant that is up to date with the version of the package